# ERD relationship - connect 2 optional entity to 1 entity

Tags: database-design, uml, entity-relationship, class-diagram, erd

i have these 3 entities student, staff and discussion.
Their relationship is such that:
1 student can post many discussion;
1 staff can post many discussion;
but 1 discussion  can only be post by either a student or a staff.
Is it ok to have both the foreign key studentID and staffID resides at discussion entity?
but doing like this may making every record in it to have 1 null value in either those 2 attribute.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying *[Second Normal Form (2NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)* will be a guideline: 
**First approach: Having a base table for People**:
You may have a `People` table to store shared properties of peoples. The Student and Staff will be child's of this table, having the Peoples table foreign-key on Discussion table will solve the problem.
**Second approach: Having a base table for Discussion**:
To reduce redundancy you may have a `Discussion-Base` table ,that would be the base table for two other entities:
`Staff-Discussion` and `Student-Discussion` tables.
 
`Discussion-Base` table will contain shared properties.

The solution is appreciated when properties of Staff-Discussion and Student-Discussion tables are varied.
If they are the same and the only difference is the optional foreign key, the design you have mentioned is efficient.
Hope this helps.

Comment: For the first approach, see [Tag:class-table-inheritance]